# Apparent incompatibility of Python Poetry with scikit-umfpack

Tags: python-poetry, umfpack

I have written a package that depends on scikit-umfpack and just discovered Python Poetry.

I am trying to setup the .toml file for poetry to manage umfpack.

When typing poetry add, it is suggested to use scikit-umfpack version 0.3.2, so it seems like poetry knows about it.

However, if I use the following dependencies in the .toml file:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
scipy = "^1.3.2"
matplotlib = "^3.1.0"
scikit-umfpack = "^0.3.2"
```

then I get the following output upon poetry update:

```
(base) fbeaudoi@fbeaudoi-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible:~/Documents/Nanoacademic/Projets/FEM/Code/poissonfem$ poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.3s)


Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing scikit-umfpack (0.3.2)

[EnvCommandError]
Command ['/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'scikit-umfpack==0.3.2'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
Collecting scikit-umfpack==0.3.2
  Using cached scikit-umfpack-0.3.2.tar.gz (25 kB)
Installing collected packages: scikit-umfpack
    Running setup.py install for scikit-umfpack: started
    Running setup.py install for scikit-umfpack: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gefcllf0/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gefcllf0/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-epnbhqeo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/include/site/python3.7/scikit-umfpack
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gefcllf0/scikit-umfpack/
    Complete output (96 lines):
    umfpack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    amd_info:
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['amd', 'amd']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        include_dirs = ['/usr/include/suitesparse']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_AMD_H', None)]
        swig_opts = ['-I/usr/include/suitesparse']

      FOUND:
        libraries = ['umfpack', 'amd', 'amd', 'umfpack']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        include_dirs = ['/usr/include/suitesparse']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_UMFPACK_H', None), ('SCIPY_AMD_H', None)]
        swig_opts = ['-I/usr/include/suitesparse', '-I/usr/include/suitesparse']

    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib/atlas-base', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib/atlas-base', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib/atlas-base', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib/atlas-base', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_info:
    C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /home/fbeaudoi/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

    creating /tmp/tmp23bo6woa/tmp
    creating /tmp/tmp23bo6woa/tmp/tmp23bo6woa
    compile options: '-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/suitesparse -I/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/include -c'
    gcc: /tmp/tmp23bo6woa/source.c
    gcc -pthread -B /home/fbeaudoi/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ /tmp/tmp23bo6woa/tmp/tmp23bo6woa/source.o -L/usr/lib -lblas -o /tmp/tmp23bo6woa/a.out
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['blas', 'blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
        include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include', '/usr/include/suitesparse', '/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/include']
        language = c
        define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

      FOUND:
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        libraries = ['blas', 'blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
        include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include', '/usr/include/suitesparse', '/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/include']
        language = c

    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building extension "scikits.umfpack.__umfpack" sources
    creating build
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/scikits
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/scikits/umfpack
    swig: scikits/umfpack/umfpack.i
    swig -python -I/usr/include/suitesparse -I/usr/include/suitesparse -I/usr/include/suitesparse -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/include -o build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/scikits/umfpack/_umfpack_wrap.c -outdir build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/scikits/umfpack scikits/umfpack/umfpack.i
    unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
    error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gefcllf0/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gefcllf0/scikit-umfpack/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-epnbhqeo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/fbeaudoi/snap/code/common/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poissonfem-7VrrSdcJ-py3.7/include/site/python3.7/scikit-umfpack Check the logs for full command output.
```

Has anyone successfully used scikit-umfpack with Python poetry and if so how ?

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with _poetry_. Read the full command output. The actual issue is at the bottom. `scikit-umfpack` needs `swig` to be built and installed on your environment.

Comment: Even pip (which is also called by poetry) alone isn't able to install it.

Comment: Thanks to sinoroc and fimswimmer. I simply needed to sudo apt-get install swig before running poetry install. Now it works.